# AS3 ExternalInterface not from Main class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to use AS3 ExternalInterface. I wrote some AS3 code which would take a screengrab of the stage of the flash and then I could use that data in JS.

It was working when I had it as the main class for flash, however I was hoping to have it as an AS file that I could import. When trying this however it doesn't seem to work.

Pastebin of my code here:

http://pastebin.com/xV1gzEkK

To init this from my main flash file I use the following code:

```
if (!grabHelper) {
    var grabHelper = new framegrabber();
}
```

In the Flash debug player I can see the trace saying that framegrabber is ready, but when I call it in JS it never works I get an error saying:

Error calling method on NPOObject.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? I am a newb with ActionScript!

Comment: grabHelper is local to the function, so nothing outside of it can get hold of it.

Comment: Can you post full code of the main flash file?

Comment: The code above is the main flash file code, pretty much apart from the line where I import the AS file. grabHelper is on the main timeline so nothing outside of it needs to get hold of it - unless I have misunderstood?

Comment: I think she meant line two conflicts with line one of your timeline sample. It can't do **if (!grabHelper)** when **grabHelper** is only then defined inside that same function as a variable. Try like this: `var grabHelper : framegrabber; if (!grabHelper) { grabHelper = new framegrabber(); }` now the IF knows what you mean. I wonder though is the IF statement even needed? If not rude to ask can you explain the logic? I think that's why Petr was asking for full timeline code.

Comment: Indeed, I suspect that grabHelp is being garbage collected.

Comment: My logic was that if grabHelper wasn't initialised I needed it initialised and as the timeline loops rounds I wanted to be sure it wouldn't get initialised multiple times.

Comment: I tried adding the code as suggested and the problem is the same. Previously I could see that framegrabber was getting initialised as the trace was showing in the debug console, however I just couldn't access the ExternalInterface from in JS.